# Creating a responsive image for a section

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm sure I have made some kind of really obvious stupid mistake here but it's been bugging me for a while now and I just cannot figure it out no matter where I look.. I am just practicing with a very basic, boring site and I need the image to be responsive in the section underneath the header, but for some reason no matter what I do, I just can't get it to work.

Sorry if this has been answered, I had a look and couldn't find anything exactly the same. If anyone could shed some light on this for me I would be very appreciative. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<html>    
<body>

      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="brand">
            <img class="brandImg" src="https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AACo_XuN80WW6m3RltLuUDD-Koivyw205OCV55h43hevVQ/12/184045382/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/network.png/EKPi4YsBGMICIAIoAg/u6N5dEYvNDRNysVhT6Arx-eKOa64tOkilzRp8K3e93Y?preserve_transparency=1&size=1600x1200&size_mode=3" alt="Brand Image">
            <h3 class="mainTitle">Network Solutions</h3>
          </div>
          <nav>
            <ul class="navBar">
              <li><a href="#">About |</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio |</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

      <section id="showcase">
      <div class="heroImg">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
      </div>
      </section>

 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
/* MAIN STYLES */
.container {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* HEADER */
header {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.brand {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.brandImg {
  height: 4em;
  width: 4em;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.mainTitle {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  left:8px;
  top: -5px;
}

/* MAIN NAVIGATION */
ul {
  float: right;
}

li {
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

/* HERO SECTION */
#showcase {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.heroImg {
  background-image: url("https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AADgiVKPX---q_yzz3R6QXjMuvUF9x1suRGMjLMV8QkZVQ/12/184045382/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/hero.jpeg/EKPi4YsBGMICIAIoAg/-UTK8zUqda_wA3F-VrZAdIZvo84OHHGWCbLEcdCi1K8?size=1600x1200&size_mode=3");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Jmp93/pen/pLEGbv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo image in your pen is throwing a 403 error. Generally speaking, you can make an image responsive with the following CSS:

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 50px; /* Width of your image */
    max-height: 50px; /* Height of your image */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle example. Drag the window to see how the image reacts.

```css
img {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 650px;
        max-height: 250px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x250" alt="Stack Overflow Test Image" />
```

Here's another example using Flexbox making the image responsive relative to another element:

```css
#test {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
h1 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  -ms-flex: none;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="Stack Overflow Test Image" />
  </div>
  <h1>This is a Test Title</h1>
</div>
```